# Is it Possible to use IFrame with Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use IFrame with Spring MVC.
Is it possible without using JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Spring has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use iframe with spring mvc.You dont require jquery **until and unless** you are initially hiding the iframe and then on some `form action` on that page you are loading the view of that action result on that iframe.

Hope this helps.Incase you need more data I would be happy to help.